# Handling Multitouch

Tags: android, button, action, motionevent

What I am trying to do is to handle multitouch buttons. I have 6 buttons and the user may touch from 1 to 6 buttons. The problem is that `MotionEvent` can handle up to 3 pointers but what I need is up to 6 pointers. Any help please?

This is the code:

```
public class MultitouchtestActivity extends Activity {
    private class TouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {


            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    sqText = "Square 1 Pressed::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount());
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    sq1Text = "Square 2 Pressed::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount());
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    sq2Text = "Square 3 Pressed::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount());
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    sq3Text = "Square 4 Pressed::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount());
                    break;
                case R.id.button5:
                    sq4Text = "Square 5 Pressed::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount());
                    break;
                case R.id.button6:
                    sq5Text = "Square 6 Pressed::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount());
                    break;
                }

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    sqText = "Square 1 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    sq1Text = "Square 2 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    sq2Text = "Square 3 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    sq3Text = "Square 4 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    sqText = "Square 1 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    sq1Text = "Square 2 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    sq2Text = "Square 3 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    sq3Text = "Square 4 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    sqText = "Square 1 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    sq1Text = "Square 2 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    sq2Text = "Square 3 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    sq3Text = "Square 4 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = "
                            + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n";
                    break;
                }




            }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected Button sq1;
    protected Button sq2;
    protected Button sq3;
    protected Button sq4;
    protected Button sq5;
    protected Button sq6;

    protected String sqText = new String();
    protected String sq1Text = new String();
    protected String sq2Text = new String();
    protected String sq3Text = new String();
    protected String sq4Text = new String();
    protected String sq5Text = new String();


    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do whatever you want to change here, like:
            updateTextField();
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setViews();
        handler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 5000);
    }

    private void setViews() {
        sq1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sq2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        sq3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        sq4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        sq5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        sq6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

        sq1.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
        sq2.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
        sq3.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
        sq4.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
        sq5.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
        sq6.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
    }

    private void updateTextField() {
        final TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView);
        final TextView view2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView1);
        final TextView view3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView2);
        final TextView view4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView3);
        final TextView view5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView4);
        final TextView view6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView5);

        // view1.append(sqText + "\n");
        view1.setText(sqText);
        view2.setText(sq1Text);
        view3.setText(sq2Text);
        view4.setText(sq3Text);
        view5.setText(sq4Text);
        view6.setText(sq5Text);

        handler.post(mUpdateUITimerTask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of pointers that you can detect with android depends on the device. Some older ones can only detect one whereas more modern ones may be able to detect more.

Please make sure that your app also works on devices with less pointers if you want to publish it on the market.

Comment: It depends on devices. Mine can detect 4 pointers at the same time.

Comment: So this is related to the hardware. Interesting !